# GridView inside Composite Server Control

Tags: gridview, controls, composite, hidden-field

I'm trying to implement in my GridView custom Server Control things that works in my application.

In the application I have HiddenField and JavaScript store in this field Cell what is clicked in GridView, so I can read this value also on server side and everything works fine.

But, when I try this implement in my Custom Composite Server Control that not works. I tried also with Sessions, but also I cannot set Session variable from Javascript.

So, I decide to create CompositeControl that have GridView and HiddenField.

Added `ChildControls`, but when add Control to my `WebForm`, `GridView` is not visible on the page. (Yes, I've addded property true before creating childcontrol)

The error:

```
Type 'MyServerControl:testGridView' does not have a public property named 'Columns'"
```

My code:

```
<cc1:testGridView ID="testGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TestId" HeaderText="TestId" SortExpression="TestId" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TestType" HeaderText="TestType" SortExpression="TestType" />
                </Columns>
</cc1:testGridView>
```

Can somebody tell where i can find some info about Composite control with GridView or help me from own experience?